# CollabNet Merge Issue In Eclipse - Shows items in merge with "No Structural Differences"

Tags: collabnet

I merge several large projects with 2000+ java files/classes.   During the larger merges, I am constantly getting results in the merge that say "No Structural Differences", but it still shows up in the sync tab as if they have changed.   Is there anyway to stop this?   I may only really have 50 files that need attention, but it show 300+ differences.   It is very time consuming to have to click through them all.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is now a year old ... the reason for this is usually that one or more svn properties were merged, so those are local changes that still need to be committed. Subclipse asks SVN via its "status" API what local changes exist and that is what drives this output. It has been over 10 years, but I seem to recall we might have added an option to view the property diff somewhere?

Probably dropping to command line and running svn diff or svn st would also show you what is happening.